# How can I trigger a function after an .each() when delay is completed?

Tags: jquery

I've been trying different approaches to my problem with suggestions found on the site but couldn't get it to work.

Need to trigger a function after the last of images has faded in and every working solution I found was triggered before the images faded in, as soon as I click the triggerin' btn.
This is the code I've been working on. Hope it's well explained and somebody can point me in the right direction, either with this code or going a different route.

jQuery

```
function logosOn() {
    $('.sections img').each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay((i++) * 200).fadeTo(500, 1);
    });
}
$('#logo').click(function(){
    logosOn()           
});
```

HTML

```
<img src="logo-big.png" alt="" id="logo" />    
<div class="sections">
    <img src="logo-interiorismo.png" alt="" />
    <img src="logo-arquitectura.png" alt="" />
    <img src="logo-arte.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [.promise()](http://api.jquery.com/promise/).

```
$('#logo').click(function(){
    logosOn();
    $('.sections img').promise().done(foo);       
});
```

---

## .promise()

> **.promise( [type ] [, target ] )**
>
> **Returns:** Promise
>
> **Description:** Return a Promise object to observe when all actions of a
> certain type bound to the collection, queued or not, have finished.

Comment: Ah, your answer is better for the current use case!

Comment: Thanks. This method keeps it simple :)

Comment: Thank you both for your help, heading to try your solutions now.
First time I hear of promise(), and I did try with an array, when and then based on other examples, but couldn't get it to work.
Again, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Promises should help you here:

```
var defs = [];
$('.sections img').each(function(i) {
    defs.push( $(this).delay((i++) * 200).fadeTo(500, 1).promise() );
});

$.when.apply(null, defs).then(function() {
    // Your callback here!
});
```

Here's a running demo: http://jsbin.com/UCukiN/3/edit